# Frequent keyboard-input delay in terminal/shell on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(64 bit) w/ LXDE

Tags: 14.04, lxde, input

As the title says, I'm having frequent input delays when using the terminal on my setup. What I mean by this is that sometimes when I type something, it takes 1-2 seconds for it to actually show up. I spend most of my time in vim, and this is where I see it the most.

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire One laptop. These are its specs: 
CPU: Intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66GHZ x2
RAM: 2 GB
Graphics: Intel IGD
HDD : 150 GB

I was previously using gnome for my desktop environment, but I found it too slow; I switched to LXDE, which I like a lot more. I noticed the lag in the gnome terminal window as well.

My CPU idles around with 5-10% activity, and my RAM usage sits at around 200mb when I first boot up.

Any help is appreciated; This lag is very frustrating when I'm trying to work in vim.

Comment: Seems that CPU powersaving options are bothering you.